# Setting camel properties from outside war

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

There have been quite a few variations on this question, however I am still having problems working out a solution.  I would like to load properties selectively from a list.  First in the list that is found gets loaded:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="locations">
       <list>
           <value>file:${catalina.home}/webapps/core.properties</value>
           <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Since I first asked this question, I found that my Tomcat instance was corrupted, so I am trying again - hopefully with more clarity.  Essentially, if the first file in the list is not found the application throws an Exception.  If the first file is found it loads correctly.  I am obviously looking for a fall through to occur to the first available properties file.

Comment: How is it failing? What does it do differently from what you expect?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve a fall-through to the first existing properties file. The `PropertiesComponent`will load all properties files it finds at the given locations, optionally ignoring locations that do not exist.

Comment: Thank you - it seems that if it cannot find the first properties file then it fails to look for the second.  I will have another look at it today.

Comment: @skyman, did you manage to solve this? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: yes, I will need to look up th code for you

Answer (score 1):

use the `ignoreMissingLocation=true` setting to ignore potentially missing file locations...

Comment: I have tried this, however as per my comment above the first failure will fail silently but not continue to load the second properties file.

Comment: hmmm...must be something else going on, I just tested this using the SpringPropertiesComponentTest and it works fine with ignoreMissingLocation=true, fails otherwise...

Comment: This doesn't work using blueprint. I tried this: <bean id="properties"
          class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:src/main/resources/splat.dev.cfg</value>
                <value>file:${env:KARAF_APP}/etc/${env:HOSTNAME}.cfg</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreMissingLocation" value="true"/>
    </bean>